# INSERT based on another table's row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to `INSERT` a row in `table_A` depending on the information in a row in `table_B`.

Is it possible to do this in an isolated way where the `SELECT` retrieval of the row from table `B` is locked until either the new row is `INSERT`ed into `table_A` or the `INSERT` is skipped due to the information in `table_B`'s row?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do? Provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear what you are trying to say , i think your problem is solved by using a trigger .
check this site for know more about trigger
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-SQL-Server

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
INSERT INTO A (columns) select columns from table B where condition;
```

Columns retrieved from the query must match the queries defined in the table A.
PostgreSQL supports MVCC, custom locking can be done but it is not recomended.